# Hero Image Getting Blurred / Low Resolution

Tags: css

I was recently trying to change the hero/banner image on my homepage and noticed that after I set the new image the quality and resolution are reduced. Even when I use the original 5312x2988 image to test, the quality somehow is still blurry.

The homepage is www.shiftins.com. This is a section of the image that shows the problem:

[image]

Can someone please help me identify what part of the CSS is causing this effect?

Here is an image of the original picture to compare to the above.

[image]

Comment: It looks fine to me. Is your 'blurred' talking about the side effect that browser resizes the image using like bicubic methods? Especially I don't see there's some CSS-effects that you mentioned for such `background-image`. Maybe you may also submit a screen-cap for us to take a look.

Comment: It seems as if you're using a 1024x450 image, as I looked through the div and saw that it was leading to a 1024x450 image

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS in the body of the question.

Comment: As Andrew and Noah point out, the page is definitely NOT referencing "the original 5312x2988 image". See my answer for details.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve How can I make the hero image reference the original upload size?

Answer (score 5):

The original image you're using now is 1024px by 450px, per 
`background-image: url(https://www.shiftins.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cheap-insurance-california-1024x450.jpg);`.  However, the `#top-wrap` element has a `max-height: 400px` so you're going to start getting some scaling issues there. Additionally, on a standard 1080p desktop resolution, the width is going to be approximately 1980px.

Could you make a 1980px by 400px version from your high-res original, and use `@media` calls for one or two other screen sizes?

Comment: I even tried uploading the max size of 5312x2988 to make sure it wasn't a sizing issue. But it still does the same thing

Comment: I think it's more likely, as stated in my answer, that scaling from 450px height to 400px height is the culprit. It's not _particularly_ blurry to my eyes either way!

Comment: Ah, I kind of understand. But why would scaling down cause a loss in quality? I thought that was a scaling up issue? And when I change the image it's definitely more noticeable. 

I tried changing the code to this and it still didn't clear things up: #top-wrap {
 position: relative;
 background: #212b32;
 min-height:450px;
 max-height:450px;
    background-attachment: initial;
    background-position: center;
}

Comment: Anytime you change the size or aspect ratio of an image, the browser has to do some resizing work, which often leads to blurriness/pixelation. Again, try cropping/scaling your original high-res image to the recommended 1980x450 exactly

Comment: Is there any other way than to use exact image size? Can I make it so that the rest of the site sits over the unchanged image?

Comment: @shictins: You're correct: downsampling should not result in a noticeable loss of quality with most algorithms because you're working with a higher-res image. Could WordPress be scaling down the image during the upload process, resulting in the 1024x450 image that the browser is then taking and blowing up, resulting in loss of quality? WordPress is usually happy to upload the original versions of my image attachments along with the large, medium and small sizes. But I don't know if the hero image is just too big here.

Comment: @shictins What, specifically, is wrong with using the exact image size? As mentioned previously, if your source image is not exactly the same dimensions as given in the CSS, there is going to be some resizing going on, and that leads to blurriness, pixelation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Noah's answer points toward what is happening, but misses that the problem is dependent on browser width.

Looking at website, the image scales with browser width. When window is narrow, image is sharp. When window exceeds image width, image is upscaled, so becomes blurry. The current "src" image http://www.shiftins.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cheap-insurance-california-1024x450.jpg is 1024 wide. Wider than that, you will get blur.

As BoltClock suggests in a comment for Noah's answer, you somehow failed to get a larger image, when you attempted to upload the full resolution.

---

TO RESOLVE: Save html for page in a browser, and find line that mentions that image path. Depending on browser and line-wrapping, near line 260 or 270, li id="nav-menu-item-1443" .. background-image:url(https://www.shiftins.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cheap-insurance-california-1024x450.jpg); ..

Now upload at a higher resolution.

Refresh client browser, and save page html. Is it still referencing that 1024x450.jpg image?  If so, then that is your problem - you aren't getting a higher resolution.

---

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION: Change what happens when the window exceeds image width. Don't allow your page body width to exceed 1024, or whatever your image width is.

BENEFIT #1: Less bandwidth usage, as you don't increase the source image file size.

BENEFIT #2: Better control over what part of image is displayed. (You'll see what I mean if you display current page on a huge monitor, full-screen -- only roof of car is visible - not good since the car is your subject matter.)

---

Code to limit page width:

-- Someone else please edit this answer to suggest how to do so? --

Comment: I like how your alternative solution sounds. How would implement this?